# MySQL transaction not rolling back on error

Tags: mysql

My proc goes something like this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    select varerrmsg as ErrorMsg;
    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT ...
    INSERT ...
    UPDATE ...
    INSERT ...
    (basically serveral statements)
    CALL sp_myProc (param1, param2);
COMMIT;
```

My problem is that 'sp_myProc' actually requires 3 parameters and during testing before I knew this, the transaction was working even though the internal proc wasn't even starting. It's odd that the transaction was committing, but I was still getting the `ErrorMsg` as a result which tells me that the handler is firing, but not rolling back.

My question is: why?

Comment: UPDATE: adding `SET autocommit=0;` before starting my transaction seems to work. I'd love to know that this is correct?

Comment: Not really. That should be redundant, after `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN WORK` (those two are equivalent). It sounds as if you aren't actually in a transaction -- that's the only reason rollback wouldn't roll back. Unfortunately, `ROLLBACK` while not in a transaction doesn't throw an error.  It silently succeeds.  You start the transaction outside the proc, then immediately call the proc, and the rollback doesn't work?  Does the proc have a `COMMIT` in it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used in my Stored procedure with a Transaction that worked for me.

```
  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
      -- ERROR
      SHOW ERRORS;
    ROLLBACK;
  END;

  DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
   BEGIN
      -- WARNING
     SHOW WARNINGS;
   ROLLBACK;
  END;
```

More Infomation can be found here

http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/06/transaction-mysql-stored-procedure/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html